# Issue with dropdown menu in angularjs when used with a filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I created a simple dropdown menu and bind data using AngularJS. It works fine

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in msr | filter:search" > 
        <td>{{r.MSR_NO}}</td>
        <td>
            <select ng-init="r.MSR_STATUS = {VALUE:r.MSR_STATUS}"
                    ng-model="r.MSR_STATUS"
                    ng-options="g.NAME for g in msrStatus track by g.VALUE" 
                    name="MSR_STATUS">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But when i filter it using a textbox, it adds unexpected value field.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
```

I'm unable to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/xC0M97NUpnqeq1Vx21Ol

Comment: where is that 'unexpected value field' ?

Comment: Inside the demo plunker i created, if we start searching for something and erase it, then some more value property is added into $scope.msr

Answer (score 0):

It's the `ng-init` that's causing your issue.

Im not sure what your trying to achieve with your code, but if you remove the `ng-init` from the select element, the filter-input will stop adding values to your model.

```
<select ng-model="r.MSR_STATUS"
        ng-options="g.NAME for g in msrStatus track by g.VALUE" 
        name="MSR_STATUS">
</select>
```

Comment: I've a simple requirement. For each item there is status field which is set from value provided from database.